# L key will not type in lowercase, but will type in caps

Tags: keyboard, windows-11

so I have this issue where my L key wont type in Lowercase unless I press Caps Lock and then hold shift to type it. Likewise if I just hold shift and press L it will type a capital L, but not a Lowercase one if I release shift. This also works happens with the semicolon key as well. No other keys do this. I have tried reinstalling the drivers, I have removed my keys from the keyboard to see if there was any debris there, but they were clean. To give you an idea this is a Zephyrus G15 Laptop running windows 11. I have also tried trouble shooting, but it says no problems were detected. I have also run a virus scan with no fix.

Also I updated my AMD software about 4 months ago when this started, but have been unable to Launch the software since, with it throwing an error saying that windows has changed the graphics driver. So I am kinda wondering if it might have something either to do with the AMD software and having a shortcut that uses L, or if it might have been a windows update that caused this. Unfortunately there are no restore points from back before this started happening. If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I also just found out that if I hold any key and push the L or : key it will type no problem both in lowercase and caps, but I must be pushing a second key to get it working right. It seems that when the computer is cold as well it doesn't like to use those keys. -_- literally keeps adding stuff to this issue...

Comment: Does this happen permanently or soemtimes

Comment: So it used to happen sporadically, then as of two weeks ago it is permanently like this. I have also as of 5 minutes ago re-downloaded the firmware for the keyboard and it still hasn't fixed it. I had originally thought it was due to hotspots, but considering the SHIFT L and : both work 100% of the time I don't think it is that.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have seen something like this is when the sticky keys have been activated.  One solution is to press and release the <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>WIN</kbd> on both sides of the keyboard, slowly and one by one.  This unlocks this mode.

There is a setup for it under **Ease of Access**, where you can turn off this feature.  In the past, on some versions of Windows, they still work even when turned off.

If you press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> 5 times, it's supposed to ask you if you want the feature on.  I suspect that it has been turned on accidentally.  I am unable to replicate it right now, but I have been able to do it in the past.

> **How to Turn on Sticky Keys?**
> There are various ways to enable Sticky Keys. We’ll see all possible ways in Windows 10 and 11.
>
> Pressing Shift
> This method is exactly the same for Windows 10 and 11.
>
> The easiest way to turn on this functionality is by pressing Shift five times in succession. Subsequently, you will see the prompt ‘Do you want to turn on Sticky Keys?‘ (as shown in the previous image) followed by a beep.
>
> Click Yes to proceed.

From [The Complete Guide to Sticky Keys on Windows 10/11](https://geekflare.com/using-sticky-keys-in-windows/)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already checked this as I thought that could be the issue, however one of the first things I always do is disable Stuckey Key, Filter key shortcuts because I find them annoying and unhelpful.

Comment: My point was that they can become enabled again.  And rather than go to the setup, you can just release the mode by pressing the keys.  Otherwise the keyboard may have become defective.  Did you spill any liquid on it ?

Comment: Negative, it just randomly said I'm not gonna work right one day.

Comment: Also I want to point out that those keys pressed together open MS365 for me XD

Comment: I also just found out that if I hold any key and push the L or : key it will type no problem both in lowercase and caps, but I must be pushing a second key to get it working right.

Comment: Then, the most likely reason is that your keyboard is defective.  You can prove it by swapping it with another computer.